# Passing an array of character pointers to a C function

Tags: c

I want to pass an array of character pointers to a C function and access each element in the array. I have globally declared an array of pointers like this.

```
char *TblList[] = { "TableA", "TableB", "TableC" };
```

As a global variable I can simply access it as `TblList[0]`, `TblList[1]` and `TblList[2]`.

I would like to pass `TblList[]` into a function that is in a different object but bound in to the program (if that makes sense).

Currently I have the function declared like this.

```
short Func(char *Tbl[])
{
    short total_tbl = 0;
    total_tbl = OCCURS(Tbl);
    ...
}
```

`OCCURS` returns a value of `1`.  I need to have 3 as there are 3 elements in the `TblList[]`.  How do I pass in `TblList` and what is the correct declaration for `Func()`?  Also, what is the correct syntax to access `Tbl[]` in `Func()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense where is `tbl` declared? why is one `tbl` all lower case and the other one isn't? And what is `OCCURS`? a function? a function like macro? If it's a function what is it's signature?

Comment: Without looking at your `OCCURS` function I can tell you right away that it cannot possibly return the count of strings in your array in any reliable way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well that in combination with the array definition, because if you insert a `NULL` at the end of the array, `OCCURS` can perfectly count the number of non-`NULL` pointers.

Comment: @iharob That would require OP to modify his `TblList`, though :-)

Comment: I don't know why you use a global array.  Check the code on OCCURS, and what is it?  You should consider compiling with `-g`.  This lets you use `gdb`, or the GnuDeBugger.  It's awesome.  Go look it up.

Comment: You can't pass arrays to functions in C. Note that `short Func(char *Tbl[])` does *not* declare the function to take an array of pointers; it declares the function to take a pointer to a pointer. This is a quirk of C syntax.

Comment: The "Tbl" is declared in the parameter list for Func().  I do not see "tbl" all in lower case in the code.  It's only "Tbl".

Comment: I work on the HP Non-Stop system (previously known as Tandem).  OCCURS is a procedure call available in the system that counts how many elements in an array.  I can assure you it works.  If I use OCCURS(TblList), it will return a value of 3.  I've tested this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know the number of array elements without additional information. This could be a separate variable, but in this example I use a `NULL` sentinel at the end of the array - in much the same way that a `nul` sentinel is used to mark the end of a `char` array (a string).

I dispensed with the `OCCUR()` function or macro, because I didn't understand your comment. I also changed the return value from `short` to `int`, the natural size of the machine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *TblList[] = { "TableA", "TableB", "TableC", NULL };

int Func(char *Tbl[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (Tbl[i] != NULL)
        i++;
    return i;
}    

int main(void)
{
    printf ("Number of array elements: %d\n", Func(TblList));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Number of array elements: 3
```

Comment: I found out what OCCURS is.  It is #define OCCURS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])).  The problem is with this define.  For some reason, it does not work if the array is passed into Func.  It works if it's used against the globally defined TblList[] but not Tbl[].  I changed it to your suggestion and used a NULL at the end of the table then use a while loop to calculate the number of elements. That worked!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, it shows that I can not "upvote" until I have 15 reputations.  I don't know where to "accept" the answer.